# I fail to understand databinding in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

In android this is simple and straightforward. In WP7 it's not (at least for me).
What I'm trying to achieve:
I want to have a ListPicker:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker>
```

I want to poupulate it with Strings (same way you do with xml arrays for spinners in android)

I want the string to be displayed to the user as an item inside the picker.
It would also be good if the solution to this supported internatiolization.
I tried creating Resources with a list of strings but couldn't figure out how to "bind" it to the control.
I don't want the string values to be hardcoded in .cs files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'standard' way to populate a `ListPicker` control is to set its `ItemsSource` property to the collection which you wish to render. The `ListPicker` has an `ItemTemplate` which details how each  item is rendered. If you do not specify an `ItemTemplate`, the default template will be used an `toString()` invoked on each of the items in your collection in order to render them.

See this tutorial for more details:

[ListPicker for WP7 in depth](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth)

So a simple example would be:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="myList"/>
```

And in code-behind:

```
myList.ItemsSource = new List<string>() {
  "one", "two", "three"
};
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I don't want the values to be hardcoded. I want the whole thing to be i18n friendly.

Comment: I could populate the list you proposed by getting the Strings from a Resource i guess. Isn't there a simplier, more direct approach to this?

Comment: What do you mean by more direct - do you mean in XAML not code?

Comment: i18n is something you have too implement yourself, by storing strings in resources dictionaries: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/global_developer/archive/2011/01/18/start-building-an-international-application-for-wp-7-part-i.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Colin's answer: you can specify the strings in XAML: from the toolkit sample code `ListPickerSample.xaml`.

You'll need to add a namepsace to the top...

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

and then...

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Header="Background">
      <sys:String>dark</sys:String>
      <sys:String>light</sys:String>
      <sys:String>dazzle</sys:String>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

You should be able to apply standard XAML i18n techniques to these strings using `{Binding}` or `{StaticResource}`